# Sync multiple and different DB to one DB (sql Server 2008)

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, ssis, synchronization

I need suggestions on how i could accomplish this...

i have 3 employee solutions 
Every solutions with its own DB

what im trying to do is to unify all these three DB into one. i would also like to be flexible enough to add some other employee solution in the future.

i would also like to use SSIS.

what i've been thinking is, creating a SSIS package where opens a DB and import all data, this SSIS package would use "something" where it says the column mapping of certain DB so the SSIS knows what clumns import...

I tried to be as clear as possible... Any ideas?
thanks in advance

Comment: What is the intention of the single DB? reporting or managing master data? Your question is very vague. Please state the intention of the single database. Also please clarify, are the three source databases different or the same? i.e. are they the same product/ version or are they different databases with different schemas?

Comment: Hi, the singl DB will be used to manage the data from the 3 different sources, this way i only have to maintain a single DB, if i add a new employee to my single DB, it should be sync wiht the rest of the sources...

the source database are different DB... they have similar columns but they wont be called exactly the same, and i think at least 1 of the three are in a Oracle db

Answer (score 0):

So if you add a new employee to the central DB it should be pushed out to the other three. If the other 3 have different schemas and different platforms then when you add an employee you need to work out which db it is going to, and you need custom insertion code for each db. Also you need to think about what happens if the same person is accidentally added to the central and remote db with slightly different information. You'll end up with a duplicate in the remote db. This is more of a master data application than a reporting application if I understand your requirement correctly.

Your first step is to come up with a schema for your central db, and this has to accomodate all of the information in the three remote db's. Then you need to think about rules ffor merging information accross all these DB's. i.e. if one DB has 'Eye Colour' and the other two don't, and you then create an employee with eye colour into your central db, but the target db doesn't have that field, is that OK? What happens if someone changes the DOB in a source DB, is that meant to update the central DB. What if you do it in both DB's at the same time - who is the winner?

What is the business problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Hi, the problem im trying to solve firstly is how to bring the employee rows from every remote db to my central db, without doing a separate package for every remote db i have... i would like to do a single generic package that knows how to bring the rows from different db. i already have a schema for the central db, this schema is real simple and every employee db should have... (name, last name, address...), if there is a row that doesnt exist on a remote db it doesnt matter. I havent decide on how to merge the info yet, i think im gonna focus on a single task first... Thanks for the answer

Comment: You cannot do a single generic package if all the data sources are slightly different. You can certainly do one package but you'll need three data flows in it, as each will need to be customised for the source.